# maven how to import

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

i am able to download the jar files for the following:

`import net.sf.opensftp.SftpResult;
import net.sf.opensftp.SftpSession;
import net.sf.opensftp.SftpUtilFactory;
import net.sf.opensftp.impl.SftpUtil;`

But i am unable to import that via `pom.xml` in maven. i tried maven repository searches on http://mvnrepository.com/, and i cannot find any for `opensftp`. What should I do in order to put maven dependencies for `opensftp` in `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like this project has been deployed to a public Maven repository. In your place I would install a Maven repository manager, such as [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus) and upload `net.sf.opensftp` to it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the needed dependencies manually using the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

This comes from the [guide found here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).  You will have to maintain the dependencies manually, but I think its the only option if a particular dependency isn't found anything on any of the open repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the downloaded jar file to local maven repository using following command

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>`

and then provide the dependency entry in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

add jar in your classpath add that location in `<systemPath></systemPath>`

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.test.maven.libs</groupId>
<artifactId>a..jar</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>
${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/your-jar-name
</systemPath>
</dependency>
```